# ondatachannel event never fires - WebRTC

Tags: javascript, node.js, webrtc

## Offer Side

```js
let pc = new RTCPeerConnection({...});
let dc = pc.createDataChannel("msg");
dc.onopen = function (e) {
  console.log("Channel Opened", e);
};
dc.onclose = function (e) {
  console.log("Channel closed");
};

let offer = await pc.createOffer();
await pc.setLocalDescription(offer);

socket.emit("offer", JSON.stringify(pc.localDescription));

socket.on("answer", function (sdp) {
  pc.setRemoteDescription(JSON.parse(sdp));
});
```

## Answer Side

```js
let pc = new RTCPeerConnection({...});
pc.ondatachannel = function (e) {
  console.log(e);
};
socket.on("offer", async function (sdp) {
  await pc.setRemoteDescription(JSON.parse(sdp));
  let ans = await pc.createAnswer();
  pc.setLocalDescription(ans);
  socket.emit("answer", JSON.stringify(ans));
});
```

Ideally `ondatachannel` event should be fired.

Can someone tell me that why this is not working?

Thanks in advance :)

#### Source code

https://github.com/ats1999/RTSP-webRTC/tree/main/webRTC/data-channel

Do `npm i` to install the server side dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You are never exchanging ICE candidates (i.e. the address and port to use) and that is necessary to establish a connection (which in turn is necessary to open a datachannel).
You have a onicecandidate handler:

```
    pc.onicecandidate = function (e) {
      if (e.candidate)
        try {
          //   pc.addIceCandidate(e.candidate);
        } catch (e) {}
      log("onicecandidate");
    };
```

but the (commented out) attempt to add the candidate to the local connection is wrong. What you need to do is to signal it to the other side via something like

```
socket.emit("candidate", JSON.stringify(e.candidate));
```

and then add it in a handler for the `candidate` event along these lines:

```
    socket.on("candidate", async function (candidate) {
       await pc.addIceCandidate(JSON.parse(candidate));
    });
```

Comment: Although, i am getting `ondatachannel` event. But earlier to writing code in file, i tried to write some code in browser console. It was working fine, when i just write code in browser dev console and transfer the offer and answer by copy/paste.

Comment: Even i was not listening on `onicecandidate` event in dev console

Comment: Can you please explain me this concept

Comment: if you do copy paste in the console the SDP you have copied may have contained the candidates as `a=candidate:...` lines.
You might want to try a codelab such as https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/webrtc-web/#2 which is explaining the concepts in more detail